# What would cause wp_insert_user role to work sporadically?

Tags: user-roles, user-registration

I use the following code in a frontend form. About 10% of the time, the new user is created as a 'subscriber'. What would cause this erratic behavior?

```php
$new_user_id = wp_insert_user(array(
  'role' => 'customer',
  'user_login' => $user_login,
  'user_pass' => $user_pass,
  'user_email' => sanitize_text_field($user_email),
  'first_name' => sanitize_text_field($user_first),
  'last_name' => sanitize_text_field($user_last),
  'user_registered' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
) );
```

I have also tried `update_user_meta( $new_user_id, 'role', 'customer' )` after the wp_insert_user to catch those that have slipped through, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Our of curiosity, when you add the `customer` role, do you add it once like `wp_insert_post`? Or do you add it on every single page load like `register_post_type`?

Comment: I register the role like so:

function add_roles_on_plugin_activation() {
   add_role( 'customer',__( 'Customer' ), array( 'read' => true ) );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'add_roles_on_plugin_activation' );